# css issue for including wrong links like /home/user/public_html/skin/

Tags: theme, css

I am using a custom theme for my Magento store with a bunch of custom modules. Everything works correctly 99% of the time, but as I enable js and css minified mode. When that's done some css paths change to `/home/user/public_html/skin/`. and an error occurs not found and frontend not opens.

Comment: flush `minify css/js` in admin and try

Comment: Already try same.

Comment: check any other extension rewrite the `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head` class

Comment: Is any other way for debugging because i am new in magento.